# How do I add Value directly below a certain field in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code, but i want to add the Name etc, directly under the "name" in excel, but this far its only adding it in row 1. Can someone help me?

Example, when i type into the name-box, i want the value to be directly under "Name" in Excel, no matter where the "Name" stands in my Excal sheet.

I'm new here and this is my first question :)

```
'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Name", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.TxtName.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TxtName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a part number"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TxtName.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TxtLocation.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TxtQuantity.Value
' .Protect Password:="password"
End With
```

- Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `On Error Resume Next` ? If iRow=1 then your found cell would have to be Row 0, which clearly can't be the case, so maybe it's not finding "Name".

Comment: @TimWilliams looking at his code, irow is intentionally never 1 so that is not an issue (the values are to always go under the cell with "Name" in it, therefore the minimum row it is ever to put the data into is row 2).

Comment: @cor if he was using `On Error Resume Next` then the result of `.find` if "name" was never found would be 0, and thus iRow would be 1. from the msdn: "This method returns Nothing if no match is found." so using on error resume next would leave irow at 1. I'd say he MUST have `on error` in there or else irow could NEVER be 1 because without `on error` the `.find` would throw a run time error if name wasnt found

Comment: @user1759942 ok i take the point that irow will be the default value of 0 in the event of nothing being found :) edit: It wouldnt be 1: .Find returning nothing would cause the arithmetic operator to error, so irow would remain at whatever value it already is - presumably the default value for an integer.

Comment: I suspect there's something missing/unclear in the question: I wonder whether "row 1" refers to the first "data" row, and maybe the OP should be using `End(xlUp)` in the "name" column to find the first empty row and not just the row directly under the headers (since the comment there states `find first empty row in database`) And @Cor_Blimey is correct that `iRow` would be zero if "Name" is not found.

Comment: the end if that line: `.Row + 1` so irow would be 1, not 0 :)

Comment: The whole line fails if "Name" is not found, so `iRow` is zero (the default value for Int/Long

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the OP really wants to populate the first empty row:

```
Dim pNum, rngName As Range

pNum = Trim(Me.TxtName.Value) 'check for a part number

If Len(pNum) = 0 Then
  Me.TxtName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a part number"
  Exit Sub
End If

'find first empty row in database
Set rngName = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Name", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not rngName is Nothing then
  With ws.cells(rows.count, rngName.Column).End(xlUp).offset(1,0).entirerow
      .Cells(1).Value = pNum
      .Cells(2).Value = Me.TxtLocation.Value
      .Cells(3).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
      .Cells(4).Value = Me.TxtQuantity.Value
  End With
Else
    msgbox "'Name' header not found!"
End if
```

Comment: good point. Reading the code comment, it does sound like there could be lots of rows and the code should be adding the new info to the first empty row, this is despite the narrative in the question that could be read to be otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below as a substitute for that section of code you posted.

```
Dim anchorCell As Range

'find first empty row in database
If ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "Name" Then
    Set anchorCell = ws.Cells(1,1)
Else
    Set anchorCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Name", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
End If

If Not anchorCell Is Nothing Then
    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.TxtName.Value) = "" Then
      Me.TxtName.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please enter a part number"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    'copy the data to the database
    'use protect and unprotect lines,
    '     with your password
    '     if worksheet is protected
    With anchorCell
    '  .Unprotect Password:="password"
      .Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.TxtName.Value
      .Offset(1, 1).Value = Me.TxtLocation.Value
      .Offset(1, 2).Value = Me.TxtDate.Value
      .Offset(1, 3).Value = Me.TxtQuantity.Value
    ' .Protect Password:="password"
    End With
End If
```

Comment: @user3438601 you're welcome, but look at Tim William's answer in case what you are looking for is to add the new data to the end of a list of data after the Name cell. Also note that I had inadvertently used .Offset(1,1) etc instead of .Offset(1,0) etc. Corrected now.